# How do I divide lines into dictionaries and assign key-value pairs to them, and append an ID for each entry?

Tags: python, dictionary, txt

I have a text file with the following column names. I want these to be the keys in my dictionary, and grab the value data from separating lines in the txt file, which contains a series of lines like such:

```
   VLAN1100    84:03:28:a8:b3:18   D   -   ge-0/0/45.0            0         0       10.68.8.189:
```

```
key_list = ['vlan name', 'mac address', 'mac flags', 'age', 'logical interface', 'nh index', 'rtr id', 'IP']

with open('prog-input.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()`
#separate column data into lines
    for line in lines:
        if 'VLAN' in line:
#skip headers
            entry = line.split()
            res = {}
            for key in key_list:
                for value in entry:
                    res[key] = value
                    entry.remove(value)
                    break
            print(res)
file.close()
```

This is correctly splitting the data into key value pairs, but not assigning them to individual dictionaries.

OUTPUT:

```
{'vlan name': 'VLAN1100', 'mac address': '94:40:c9:3a:44:1a', 'mac flags': 'D', 'age': '-', 'logical interface': 'ge-0/0/16.0', 'nh index': '0', 'rtr id': '0', 'IP': '10.68.14.67'}
{'vlan name': 'VLAN1100', 'mac address': '94:40:c9:3a:91:b6', 'mac flags': 'D', 'age': '-', 'logical interface': 'ge-0/0/8.0', 'nh index': '0', 'rtr id': '0', 'IP': '10.68.14.59'}
{'vlan name': 'VLAN1100', 'mac address': '94:40:c9:3a:e5:b2', 'mac flags': 'D', 'age': '-', 'logical interface': 'ge-0/0/17.0', 'nh index': '0', 'rtr id': '0', 'IP': '10.68.14.68'}
{'vlan name': 'VLAN1100', 'mac address': 'f4:a7:39:9c:4c:e0', 'mac flags': 'D', 'age': '-', 'logical interface': 'ge-0/0/47.0', 'nh index': '0', 'rtr id': '0', 'IP': '10.68.8.191'}`
```

I only care about the key:value pairs of 0, 1, 4, 7. I would like to assign each line entry with an ID, possibly based on the 'mac address', which is unique.

I also tried using this code, but I don't understand how to use map, so I'd rather it be spelled out:

```
        if 'VLAN' in line:
            device = {k:v for k, *v in map(line.split, file)}
            for key in key_list:
                for value in device:
                    device.append()
print(device)
```

But it doesn't work. I want to be able to create a dictionary for each line item, and then put them inside a List, to query later.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the input txt file?

Comment: The first example appears to be printing out separate dicts. What exact output would you like to see, and how does it differ from the output you are getting?

Comment: Yes, the txt file input contains many lines like this:Ethernet switching table : 570 entries, 570 learned
Routing instance : default-switch
    Vlan                MAC                 MAC         Age    Logical                NH        RTR 
    name                address             flags              interface              Index     ID
    
VLAN1100            28:29:86:46:27:c7   D             -   ge-0/0/42.0            0         0        10.68.8.213
  
  VLAN1100            28:29:86:46:27:c9   D             -   ge-0/0/43.0            0         0

Comment: It is unclear what your desired output is. Please provide an example.

Comment: Desired output would be to store each line as its own dictionary and programmatically generate ID #s or names for them. Each dictionary should contain k:v pairs per the key_list on line 1. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean create a new variable for each dictionary? Like `data1 = {'vlan name': 'VLAN1100'....}`, `data2 = {'vlan name': 'VLAN1100'....}`? I don't recommend that. Use a list. Ex: `all_data = [dict(zip(key_list, line.split())) for line in lines]`.

Comment: Yes, a list storing the dictionaries would make sense. I'm happy to try this. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp this seems to work, but how do I query what is inside this List 'all_data'? I can do >>> print(all_data[1])
{'vlan name': 'SE', 'mac address': '-', 'mac flags': 'statistics', 'age': 'enabled,', 'logical interface': 'NM', 'nh index': '-', 'rtr id': 'non', 'IP': 'configured'} but how do I get a list of dictionaries inside the list?

Comment: Do you mean to filter it, say based on mac address for example? You can use a list comprehension: `filtered = [data_dict for data_dict in all_data if data_dict['mac address'] == '94:40:c9:3a:44:1a']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251374/discussion-between-turkishpoptart-and-johnny-mopp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly generalised method, that only uses built-ins, which you can use to perform similar tasks to the one you have specified.

```py
import operator


def split_lines_to_dicts(lines, column_map, line_filter, id_generator):
    value_getter = operator.itemgetter(*list(column_map.keys()))
    column_names = list(column_map.values())

     return [
        dict(
            zip(column_names, value_getter(line.split())),
            id=next(id_generator)
        )
        for line in lines
        if line_filter(line)
    ]
```

To show how you might use that I'll show it with details plugged in from your situation:

```py
import io
import itertools


print(split_lines_to_dicts(
    # You would use a file handle here
    lines=io.StringIO("""
        # Ignore me
        VLAN1100    84:03:28:a8:b3:18   D   -   ge-0/0/45.0            0         0       10.68.8.189
        VLAN1100    84:03:28:a8:b3:18   D   -   ge-0/0/45.0            0         0       10.68.8.189
        VLAN1100    84:03:28:a8:b3:18   D   -   ge-0/0/45.0            0         0       10.68.8.189
        ...
    """),
    # The position to the name we want in the output
    column_map={
        0: "vlan name",
        1: "mac address",
        4: "logical interface",
        7: "IP"
    },
    # A filter to decide which lines to keep
    line_filter=lambda line: "VLAN" in line,
    # A generator of ids, you could change this to do something else
    id_generator=itertools.count()
))
```

This would give you a list like this:

```py
[
    {'vlan name': 'VLAN1100', 'mac address': '84:03:28:a8:b3:18', 'logical interface': 'ge-0/0/45.0', 'IP': '10.68.8.189', 'id': 0}, 
    {'vlan name': 'VLAN1100', 'mac address': '84:03:28:a8:b3:18', 'logical interface': 'ge-0/0/45.0', 'IP': '10.68.8.189', 'id': 1}, 
    {'vlan name': 'VLAN1100', 'mac address': '84:03:28:a8:b3:18', 'logical interface': 'ge-0/0/45.0', 'IP': '10.68.8.189', 'id': 2}
]
```

Comment: I keep getting "TypeError: split_lines_to_dicts() got multiple values for argument 'lines'"

Can't get this to work sadly

Answer (score 1):

```
import io    
import csv
import pandas as pd

file_content="""
VLAN1100    94:40:c9:3a:44:1a   D   -   ge-0/0/16.0 0   0   10.68.14.67
VLAN1100    94:40:c9:3a:91:b6   D   -   ge-0/0/8.0  0   0   10.68.14.59
VLAN1100    94:40:c9:3a:e5:b2   D   -   ge-0/0/17.0 0   0   10.68.14.68
VLAN1100    f4:a7:39:9c:4c:e0   D   -   ge-0/0/47.0 0   0   10.68.8.191
"""

key_list = ['vlan name', 'mac address', 'mac flags', 'age',
            'logical interface', 'nh index', 'rtr id', 'IP']


# with open("csv.abc") as fobj: #
#     records = csv.DictReader(fobj, fieldnames=key_list, delimiter="\t")

file_buffer = io.StringIO(file_content)
records = csv.DictReader(file_buffer, fieldnames=key_list, delimiter="\t")

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df = df.iloc[:, [0,1,4,7]]
df.to_dict("records")
```

[{'vlan name': 'VLAN1100',
'mac address': '94:40:c9:3a:44:1a',
'logical interface': 'ge-0/0/16.0',
'IP': '10.68.14.67'},
{'vlan name': 'VLAN1100',
'mac address': '94:40:c9:3a:91:b6',
'logical interface': 'ge-0/0/8.0',
'IP': '10.68.14.59'},
{'vlan name': 'VLAN1100',
'mac address': '94:40:c9:3a:e5:b2',
'logical interface': 'ge-0/0/17.0',
'IP': '10.68.14.68'},
{'vlan name': 'VLAN1100',
'mac address': 'f4:a7:39:9c:4c:e0',
'logical interface': 'ge-0/0/47.0',
'IP': '10.68.8.191'}]

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I typed it out with the # part uncommented and included my .txt file. How do I view the records, or how do I view the records once this data is done? Or you just have to copy and paste it into "file_content"?

Comment: is up to you how you  wanna see the records, the #commented line is for you just in case your input is in a file. copy paste is not required.  for example you can print out the records one by one -> for entry in records: print(entry)